# How to create an embedded an array from a table using pentaho data integration in a existing mongo document

Tags: pentaho-data-integration

I have an existing mongo collection called:

University (univ_id, .....)

I want to run a pentaho transformation to add a new field
(faculties) from the original relational db

Faculty (id, name, univ_id,....)

This step is supposed to create an array to insert using the MongoDB Inset step.

I have tried to create the array using the group by and Jason output steps but haven't been able to make it work.

Can anyone recommend any solutions? I tried checking the official wiki, but the referenced solution is not available